# Google Analytics: Not Possible to Get conversion rate of Non-subscribers

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to track the conversion rate of visitors to my application.  Most of the traffic is already paying customers.  Paying customers hit the home page, but also pages like /dashboard, /login, etc.  They also have an UserId set in analytics.  Prospects only hit the home page and sales pages.  I have no problem creating traffic segments for Users vs Prospects.

I have segments All, Users and Prospects.  All is everyone, Users are anyone who has UserId = Assigned, or visited the /dashboard, etc, and Prospects which is basically the opposite of users, ie traffic that hasn't hit the dashboard, or have a UserId assigned.

But it seems like Google Analytics has a fundamentally flawed, because there is no way to get a true conversion rate of only Prospects. That is because the moment they convert they turn into users.  So by definition the number of prospects that have converted is always zero.

[image]

I can manually calculate the conversion rate by using the number of prospects in a given week, and the number of conversions (signups events), but there is no way to show that in the system.  I can show the conversion rate of all traffic, but that isn't very helpful because most of it is already users who will never convert again.

I assume I am missing something. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I would add a new View for this just tracking all your Prospects. This could help you perform reports just on your Prospect Users.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom dimension (session scoped) for anyone that you do not have a user ID for. So before your pageview your code could look something like

```
var userID = getUserID()
if(!userID){
ga('set','dimensionX','Prospect');
}
```

The point is that the dimension would only be set when you don't have a user ID and so once a user converts and they now presumably have a user ID the dimension stating they are a prospect will be retained for the remainder of their session.

docs on custom dimensions
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets